using Is operator with OR condition and another Is operator in C#
if(foo.Goo is Hoo1 hoo1)
{
    hoo1.someProperty = ....
}
else if(foo.Goo is Hoo2 hoo2)
{
    hoo2.someProperty = ...
}
else ....

I wonder if there is an OR option I can use (somePrperty is the same property for hoo1 and hoo2)

Actually the same property, or just two separately-declared properties with the same name and type? Is there some common base type that declares the property? A [mcve] would help here.

Is it an option to use an interface which defines this someProperty property?

@JonSkeet the same name and type (both decimal)
I agree it can be written better, but its the workplace and this is how the engineers decided to do

@Progman unfortunately not

You could make it even UGLIER by using Reflection...but then you'd end up with even more code than you started with.

If you could show a little more code, we could probably use a pattern matched switch statement to accomplish what you want.

You cannot create a variable with the 'not' or 'or' pattern. The following code is invalid:
if(foo.Goo is Hoo1 hoo1 or Hoo2 hoo2)

Instead, I would suggest that both Hook1 and Hook2 implement an interface that contains your 'someProperty'. Then, you can set the 'someProperty' from the if block.
if(foo.Goo is IHoo hoo) 
{
    hoo2.someProperty = ...;
}


Even though I know your solution is the correct solution, this is my work's code... it is very very large and I can't change it to that extension

As already been said, if Hoo1 and Hoo2 are different classes, without a common ancestor (superclass or interface), you can't do much.
As the is operator just returns a boolean value, you could write something like:
    if (foo.Goo is Hoo1 hoo1 || foo.Goo is Hoo2 hoo2)
    { ... }

But you would end up with two names for the same thing, and that's not what you want. Actually, you'll get an undefined variable hoo1 (or hoo2) when trying to reference one name (or the other) inside the block.
This could be solved avoiding the is and doing something (really ugly) like this:
    if (foo1 is Hoo1 || foo2 is Hoo2) {
      Object fooX = foo1 is not null ? foo1 : foo2;
      ((Hoo1) fooX).someProperty = 1;
    }

or even like this (uglier):
    if (foo1 is Hoo1 || foo2 is Hoo2) {
        Hoo1 fooX = foo1 is not null ? foo1 : (Hoo1) ((Object) foo2);
            fooX.someProperty = 1;
    }


I must said that, ugliness apart, the run-time checks associated with dynamic dispatching should signal an exception when foo1 is not a Hoo1 (and the block is entered because of foo2). And that's right because, as it has already been said, it's not the "same property", but two different (unrelated) properties with just the same name.
